# Choose gateway regarding incomming node

Tags: linux, routing, iptables, gateway

I have a server behind 2 Internet Access.
the ip are these:

-Server : 192.168.0.1

-ISP 1 : 192.168.0.253

-ISP 2 : 192.168.0.254

I would like that packets coming from ISP 1 receive response using ISP 1 as gateway and packet packets coming from ISP 1 receive response using ISP 2.

Does anybody knows how I could do this?

Many thanks by advance for your help.

Proc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
-ISP 1 : 192.168.1.253 eth0 - default gateway
-ISP 2 : 192.168.0.254 eth1
```

The following commands create an alternate routing table via eth1 for packets that have the mark 1

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1
ip route add 127.0.0.0/0 table 1 dev lo
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 table 1 dev eth1
```

The other half of the job is recognizing packets that must get the mark 1, replace 192.168.0.254 by the address of the non-default-route interface:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.0.254 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

The following doesn't require any packet marking with ipfilter. The outgoing (reply) packets will have the IP address that was originally used to connect to the 2nd interface as the source (from) address on the outgoing packet.

```
echo 200 isp2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 192.168.0.254 dev eth1 table isp2
ip route add default via <gateway_IP> dev eth1 table isp2
```